# MS SQL Insert most recent three dates from one table into another table matching on one column

Tags: sql

I have a 'source' table containing a list of user logins along with the date and time of login. The 'source' table looks like this...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSrc](
[userID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[date] [datetime] NULL)
```

For illustration purposes some rows may contain...

```
userID    date
------    ----
1         2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
2         2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
3         2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
2         2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
3         2013-01-03 00:00:00.000
3         2013-01-04 00:00:00.000
1         2013-01-02 00:00:00.000
3         2013-01-05 00:00:00.000
```

I have a 'destination' table as follows...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDest](
[userID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[date1] [datetime] NULL,
[date2] [datetime] NULL,
[date3] [datetime] NULL)
```

The userID in the source table contains multiple duplicate userID's whereas I've populated the destination table with unique userID's.

What I need to do is to itterate through the source table and insert the last three login dates per user?

So by way of example the destination table would like this using userID '3'

user '3' has 4 entries in the source table

```
userID    date1                     date2                     date3
------    -----                     -----                     -----
3         2013-01-05 00:00:00.000   2013-01-04 00:00:00.000   2013-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

date1 being the most recent login date, date2 then next and date3 the next.

I can get the latest date from the source table per userID but I can't figure out how to get the three most recent (assuming there are three dates) and insert them into the destination table.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL should work:

```
 with userrows as
(SELECT t.userID, t.date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.userID ORDER BY t.date DESC) AS Row
FROM tblSrc t)
insert into tblDest
select distinct
    u.userID,
(select top 1 date from userrows u1 where u1.userID=u.userID and u1.Row=1 ) 'date1',
(select top 1 date from userrows u2 where u2.userID=u.userID and u2.Row=2)  'date2',
(select top 1 date from userrows u3 where u3.userID=u.userID  and u3.Row=3)  'date3'
from userrows u
```

To add status you could do something like this:

```
 with userrows as
(SELECT t.userID, t.date,t.status,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.userID ORDER BY t.date DESC) AS Row
FROM tblSrc t)
insert into tblDest
 select distinct
u.userID,
(select date from userrows u1 where u1.userID=u.userID and u1.Row=1 ) 'date1',
(select status from userrows u1 where u1.userID=u.userID and u1.Row=1 ) 'status1',
(select date from userrows u2 where u2.userID=u.userID and u2.Row=2)  'date2',
(select status from userrows u2 where u2.userID=u.userID and u2.Row=2 ) 'status2',
(select date from userrows u3 where u3.userID=u.userID  and u3.Row=3)  'date3',
(select status from userrows u3 where u3.userID=u.userID and u3.Row=3 ) 'status3'
 from userrows u
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the respoonse. Using the above I get the following. "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." There are a few additional columns in the source and destination tables, I wasn't sure if they were significant. The column names though are correct.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I've created a new 'destination' table with only the userID, date1, date2, and date3 columns and the query is executing. So pardon my ignorance at not realising the additional destination columns were significant. Is there any other way around this or will I have to copy the results over when it's complete (the query is still running as there are ~260M records) so I'm assuming at this point it will work.

Comment: Update from the last comment. Left running overnight and still not finished! Canceled the query and created a much smaller dataset of 40K records. That executed in a minute and worked of a fashion. The issue I see but don't understand is that date1 and date 2 are always the same values. Date3 is does vary. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: I do have another query to add to the original. If each entry has an associated status code, as in "success" or "failure", how can you modify the above SQL to accommodate each date entries status. The destination table will have three additional columns called status1, status2 and status3, so date1 entry would have the status1 entry updated appropriately.

Comment: If I knew it was that amount of data, I might have suggested a different solution :-), but you maybe could take a part of the data at a time (like you did with the 40K rows)... I edited my answer to show how to add the status in the same style.

Comment: And the question about data variation, can't it just be that the rows just got the same values? with 260M rows sorted by date you probably have a few with same values (check a few random samples maybe?).

Comment: Thank you for your time Daniel, it's much appreciated. I will break it down into smaller chunks though it's going to take some time and effort.